# Push Notifications for External Beta Testers

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

How do I allow push notifications to start working for my beta testers. At the moment, my phone is the only one that can receive push notifications since I have gotten a certificate for it. My app ID has a certificate for development and distribution.

I am using external testers and I'm using Parse.com to send push notifications. The logic with sending the push is working, but they are still not getting received on anyone's end but mine.

Do I actually have to add everyone UUID to a certificate even for external testers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add UDID for external tester. You can upload application on iTunes and distribute it via Test flight with external tester. Once you upload application on iTunes, you can upload .p12 file of production. Once you follow above steps, you can test Push Notification for External Tester.

Comment: this is right, I just got it working do this an hour ago.